# Using the fs library in sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit

I want to find out if it's possible to use the fs library in svelte kit endpoints

I have searched around for solutions but I don't get any. I was thinking of creating a separate node server with express and use the fs library from there but I want to find out if it's possible to do it in sveltekit